# how did the compiler figure out the template types from map

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am a timid user with template and usualy follow the routine example cases.

so, I am quite surprised to see the following code.

```
template<typename Table> void set(Table& tbl,
const typename Table::key_type& key,
const typename Table::mapped_type& attr)
{
  typename Table::iterator iter = tbl.find(key);
  if (iter != tbl.end()) {
    iter->second = attr;
  } else {
    typedef typename Table::key_type TableKey;
    typedef typename Table::mapped_type TableNonKey;
    tbl.insert( std::pair<TableKey,TableNonKey>(key,attr) );
  }
}

template<typename Table> void show(Table& tbl)
{
  for (typename Table::iterator iter = tbl.begin();
    iter != tbl.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->second << endl;
  }
}

int main(){
  std::map<int, int> table_obj;
  set(table_obj, 1, 2);
  show(table_obj);
}
```

How does the compiler know that Table is std::map and able to deduct out Table::key_type and Table::mapped_type from it, when it comes to compile show/set function? Are there any other similar use cases with template?

Comment: The compiler learns that `Table` must be `std::map<int, int>` through a process called [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

Comment: key_type and mapped_type are typedefs in the map class. Any class that has these typedefs and the functions you call, such as find and end, can be used as the template parameter.

Comment: Note that `Table::key_type` and `Table::mapped_type` are non-deductible (but `Table` was previously deducted).

Comment: [OT]: `set` may be rewritten as `{ tbl[key] = attr; }`.

Comment: `set` _should_ be written like that, otherwise it does the lookup twice when inserting a new key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main` the compiler knows the type of 'table' and then use the [Koenig Lookup](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-personal-note-about-argument-dependent/232901443)/[ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) to find a fitting `set` in this case trivially as there is only one.

Declaration

```
template<typename Table> void set(Table& tbl,
const typename Table::key_type& key,
const typename Table::mapped_type& attr);
```

Implementation

```
template<typename Table> void set(Table& tbl,
const typename Table::key_type& key,
const typename Table::mapped_type& attr) {
  typename Table::iterator iter = tbl.find(key);
  if (iter != tbl.end()) {
    iter->second = attr;
  } else {
    typedef typename Table::key_type TableKey;
    typedef typename Table::mapped_type TableNonKey;
    tbl.insert( std::pair<TableKey,TableNonKey>(key,attr) );
  }
}
```

`key_type` and `mapped_type` are typedefs from [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

If you had called 'set' this way

```
std::vector<int> NotAMap;
set(NotAMap, 1, 2);
```

The loopup would still have found 'set' and at start found that Table might be a std::vector, but std::vector doesn't have a `mapped_type` so is it rejected as a candidate.

Comment: can we put main and the template into different compile units? if so, how will the compiler deduct that "table" is a type of map?

Comment: The template must be visible in the unit that uses it (declaration), then somewhere its implementation must be instantiated with the concrete type to be able to link.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
  std::map<int, int> table_obj;
  set(table_obj, 1, 2);
  show(table_obj);
```

Your question:

> How does the compiler know that Table is std::map and able to deduct
>   out Table::key_type and Table::mapped_type from it, when it comes to
>   compile show/set function?

Answer: because the type of `table_obj` is known.

Just put yourself in the position of the compiler. In line 1, you see that `table_obj` is a `std::map<int, int>`. So in line 2 and 3, what else should you do? You *can* only instantiate the template functions `set` and `show` with `Table` = `std::map<int, int>`. There is no ambiguity.

If you try to instantiate the functions with other types, errors will occur:

```
set<double>(table_obj, 1, 2);                    // error
set<void>(table_obj, 1, 2);                      // error
set<std::map<int *, char *> >(table_obj, 1, 2);  // error
set<std::map<double, int> >(table_obj, 1, 2);    // error
set<std::map<int, int> >(table_obj, 1, 2);       // OK
```

As you can see, specifying the type is **redundant**. So C++ allows you to omit it.

This feature of the language is called [**template argument deduction**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

---

> Are there any other similar use cases with template?

Almost every use of a standard algorithm.

Consider this example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 123);
}
```

Without template argument deduction, the last line would have to be written as:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::find<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>(v.begin(), v.end(), 123);
}
```